# OBJ File exporting with missing geometry

Tags: modeling, export

I'm new to Blender and I've recently done one of my first exports of an obj file on a house candle model I've created. After exporting, I see holes in my mesh and various other unwanted artifacts. It looks perfect in Blender, but looks heinous after exporting. Any suggestions?

[image: Another screenshot in blender[![][1]]Exported model1]1]

Comment: Hello maybe make sure that you don't have some faces that are not correctly oriented? In Blender, in Edit mode, select all and Shift N